# Storing vast amounts of "uptime" data for a website monitoring service

Tags: sql, laravel, design-patterns, database-design

this is more of a general discussion rather than a code question.

I have a website monitoring platform whereby users of the system can input their website URL and we'll check it every X minutes based on the customer's interval, at each interval, an entry is stored as a `UptimeCheck` model in the Laravel 8 project with the status being down or up.

If a customer has 20 monitors, and each checks every minute, then over a 30 day period for the one customer they'd accumulate over 1 million rows.

My query, is really do I need to keep this number of rows?

The reason this number of rows is kept is so that we can present a graph showing the average website uptime.

My thinking is that if I created some kind of SVG programatically for each day and store this in the table then I wouldn't need to store as many entries, but my concern here is how would I merge SVG models into one to present a daily graph?

What kind of libraries could I use and how else might I approach this?

Comment: Would this require you to keep all datapoints for the level of accuracy you're looking for or could you average out points across time to remove older data. You'll probably have to weigh up how much you value points of accuracy compared to how much data you need to store.

Comment: Right now, data is technically averaged, but the records are retained to allow customers more granular detail. Beyond a few days I suppose data could be averaged, how how would I approach this with my `UptimeCheck` model

Answer (score 0):

Unlike performance, the trick for storing uptime data is simple. You don't store it. ;)
You need to store DOWNTIME data instead. Register only unavailability events and extrapolate uptime when displaying reports.

Comment: That's an interesting thought. If I'm only ever storing downtime data, then how would I alert of uptime from a downtime event?

Comment: Expanding on this, would it be necessary to store each point between? Given one point remains consistent could there be a starting time of the period and each x minutes when checking we update the ending timestamp for the period. When the status changes, make a new record. This way you're only recording the periods of change and can extrapolate any other data